# Ubuntu 16.04, WiFi not working (Qualcomm Atheros 9565)

Tags: networking, wireless, hp, ath9k

I installed Xubuntu 16.04 in my HP 245 G2 laptop, and everything works fine but the WiFi. I have a Qualcomm Atheros 9565 WiFi card and Xubuntu tells me that WiFi is disabled. I had the same problem with Ubuntu and a live USB drive with Linux Mint.

When I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, the WiFi light indicator turns red (off) for a millisecond and then turns back to the white light (on).

Ubuntu supposedly comes with the default drivers for the card so I didn't install anything.

Here is the output of a few commands:

```
$ sudo rfkill unblock all
$ sudo rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
$ sudo modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath
[   23.046369] ath: phy0: WB335 1-ANT card detected
[   23.046375] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   23.061786] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   23.065354] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[   23.065362] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6a
[   23.065364] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   23.065369] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   23.065371] ath: Regpair used: 0x6a
[   23.356577] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   24.164539] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question to mark it solved or to add a solution. Instead, add an answer below (in the answers section) and mark the question solved by clicking the checkmark next to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by running in terminal:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf <<< "blacklist hp_wmi"
```

and after a reboot the wifi works!!!